# DPDK pktgen run.py error - Config file 'default' not found

Tags: dpdk

I am learning pktgen based on DPDK. There is no problem during the DPDK's process(for example, installation, allocating large pages, binding NICs, running DPDK sample programs, etc.). I follow [Getting Started with Pktgen](http://pktgen-dpdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) and when I run `run.py` it shows an empty list of config files. Then I try to execute the instructions on the doc, I get an error says "Config file 'default' not found".

```
root@ubuntu:/home/chang/pktgen-dpdk/tools# ./run.py 
>>> sdk '/home/chang/dpdk', target 'x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc'
*** Pick one of the following config files

Configurations:
   Name             - Description
   ----               -----------
root@ubuntu:/home/chang/pktgen-dpdk/tools#  ./run.py -s default
>>> sdk '/home/chang/dpdk', target 'x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc'
*** Config file 'default' not found
Configurations:
   Name             - Description
   ----               -----------
root@ubuntu:/home/chang/pktgen-dpdk/tools#
```

But in fact, the configuration file does exist in `/pktgen-dpdk/cfg`

```
root@ubuntu:/home/chang/pktgen-dpdk/cfg# ls
bond.cfg          default.cfg     pktgen-1.cfg      server_mif.cfg
client_memif.cfg  half-bond.cfg   pktgen-2.cfg
client_mif.cfg    many-cores.cfg  server_memif.cfg
```

My system is Ubuntu 18.04 installed on VMware. I tried to re-clone the code, re-compile dpdk and pktgen, tried to install it on another machine, but got the same error.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like we have to run the script from the main project directory, i.e. do `cd ..` and try again. Here is the quote from the [README.md](https://git.dpdk.org/apps/pktgen-dpdk/tree/README.md#n368)

> Using the new tools/run.py script to setup and run pktgen with different configurations. The configuration files are located in the cfg directory with filenames ending in .cfg.
>
> To use a configuration file;

```
$ ./tools/run.py -s default  # to setup the ports and attach them to DPDK (only needed once per boot)
$ ./tools/run.py default     # Run the default configuration
```